# How should SSE flags be added with modern CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to follow the guidelines for modern cmake >= 3.0 at least, where I don't assume anything about the compiler and use target based commands.

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk
or search "effective cmake".

#### So, how then, when my target depends on SSE 4.1, should I be declaring this information?

I was actually expecting FindSSE to include an interface target with no source but carries it's own appropriate linker flags. But it only states if SSE versions are present on the host.

This varies by platform, so like:
/arch:sse4.1 vs -msse4.1

So am I missing something internal to cmake that handles this setting for different compilers or do I just need to check the platform and set target_compile_options accordingly?

Comment: Concerning the first point: you could encapsulate the variables set by FindSSE into a pure interface target that you write yourself. Your own targets can then link against this (private). It's more for you to write, but as long as the new guidelines haven't been embraced everywhere, you don't have many choices.

Answer (score 5):

Based on lubgr's reply, I devised this:

```
add_library(sse4_1 INTERFACE IMPORTED)
if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(sse4_1 INTERFACE /arch:SSE4.1)
else()
    target_compile_options(sse4_1 INTERFACE -msse4.1)
endif()
```

Comment: It seems fine, and since it comes up repeatedly, having the target I can inject seems handy. It's certainly better than having to do the if/else on every target. Though, I still feel a little weird whenever I have to enter compiler specific flags in cmake. Perhaps SIMD settings will make their way to the compile features eventually.

Answer (score 3):

For global flags, that are used by *all* targets in the project it is perfectly fine to still use the non-target based approach, eg. by calling [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_compile_options.html).

For maintainability reasons, you should do this in one place only, preferably close to the root `CMakeLists.txt`.

This saves you from having to repeat the same target dependency everywhere throughout the project. Note though that this relies somewhat on programmer discipline: As soon as you have singular targets that need different flags or you start introducing multiple places where the global flags are being set, this can quickly turn into a maintenance nightmare.